# this code can't be run by a patch

Tags: simulation, netlogo

This error comes up when I try to determine to nearest patch that would take the turtle to its destination.

```
this code can't be run by a patch
error while turtle 0 running DISTANCE
    called by procedure GO
    called by Button 'go'
```

This is the problematic code:

```
let nearest-patch min-one-of patches in-cone 1 180 [distance dest]
        if not any? other turtles-on nearest-patch 
        [ face nearest-patch
          fd 1 ]
```

Full code:

```
to go
  reset-ticks
  ask turtles
  [  
     ; going to the center, then goal
     if dest = patch 0 0 and distance patch 0 0 < 3 
     [ repeat 5 [ fd 1 ]
       set dest goal ]

     ; wrapping around and going to the center, then goal
     if distance goal < 3 
     [ repeat 5 [ fd 1 ]
       set dest patch 0 0 ]

       face dest

    let nearest-patch min-one-of patches in-cone 1 180 [distance dest]
    if not any? other turtles-on nearest-patch 
    [ face nearest-patch
      fd 1 ]

  ]
  tick
end
```

Help?

Comment: I ran your code above and did not get any error, with goal = patch 0 0.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand why you use dest and goal, but anyway I think your code has two problems, for first one :

```
if distance goal < 3
```

You did not initialize goal before calling it so it will mean `if distance 0 < 3` which will give you an error, goal only  has a value if your first condition is met (if dest = patch 0 0 and distance dest < 3)

and your error for `this code can't be run by a patch` is caused when a patch wants to use a turtle variable, I usually save the turtle variable in a local variable and call it indirectly, but there might be better ways which I am not aware of I am new to netlogo too ;)

```
turtles-own [dest goal]
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10 [
    move-to patch random 15 random 15
  ]
end
to go
  reset-ticks
  ask turtles
  [  
    ; going to the center, then goal
    set dest patch 0 0

    if dest = patch 0 0 and distance dest < 3 
      [ repeat 5 [ fd 1 ]
        set goal dest ]

    ; wrapping around and going to the center, then goal

    if distance goal < 3 
      [ repeat 5 [ fd 1 ]
        set dest patch 0 0 ]

    face dest
    let d dest
    let nearest-patch min-one-of patches in-cone 1 180 [distance d]
    if not any? other turtles-on nearest-patch 
    [ face nearest-patch
      fd 1 ]

  ]
  tick
end
```